# merge in R - one column changes value

Tags: r, merge

I'm merging one df into another. This normally works fine for me using:

```
df<-merge(x,y, by=c(variable1, variable2))
```

actual code used

```
merge(mymaindf, mergingdf, by=c('hai_dispense_number','ID'))
```

My problem is that with the data i'm using right now, one variable from x will not keep it's values. Its a binary variable, with about half and half 0 and 1. When I merge x and y, the values in this variable all change to 1. I've tried various things like changing the variable from a numerical, to character to factor varaible - but no luck. I also tried making the variable in y, but it also changes on merging. Does anyone know what could be happening? I have included a dput for both dfs (`x = mymaindf` and `y = mergingdf`) below.

The variable that changes is called scheme.

mymaindf:

```
structure(list(hai_dispense_number = c("Patient HAI0000059", 
"Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", 
"Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", 
"Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059"
), ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), 
    variable.x = structure(1:10, .Label = c("month1", "month2", 
    "month3", "month4", "month5", "month6", "month7", "month8", 
    "month9", "month10", "month11", "month12", "month13", "month14", 
    "month15", "month16", "month17", "month18"), class = "factor"), 
    adherence = c(1, 1, 0.933333333333333, 0.966666666666667, 
    0.966666666666667, 0.966666666666667, 0.9, 0.966666666666667, 
    0.633333333333333, 0.866666666666667), time1 = c(-1, -2, 
    -3, -4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), new_numbers = c(-4L, -3L, -2L, 
    -1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), variable.y = structure(1:10, .Label = c("t1", 
    "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", "t9", "t10", "t11", 
    "t12", "t13", "t14", "t15", "t16", "t17", "t18"), class = "factor"), 
    age = c(72, 72.0833333333333, 72.1666666666667, 72.25, 72.3333333333333, 
    72.4166666666667, 72.5, 72.5833333333333, 72.6666666666667, 
    72.75), sex = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), post = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), time_post = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5), base = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
    scheme = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"
    )), .Names = c("hai_dispense_number", "ID", "variable.x", 
"adherence", "time1", "new_numbers", "variable.y", "age", "sex", 
"post", "time_post", "base", "scheme"), row.names = c("1", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "2"), class = "data.frame")
```

mergingdf:

```
structure(list(hai_dispense_number = c("Patient HAI0000059", 
"Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", 
"Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", 
"Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059"
), aspT1person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), aspT2person = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), aspT3person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), aspbaseperson = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    lipidT1person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lipidT2person = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lipidT3person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lipidbaseperson = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), hyptenT1person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), hyptenT2person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hyptenT3person = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hyptenbaseperson = c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), insulinT1person = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), insulinT2person = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), insulinT3person = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), insulinbaseperson = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    aspirin = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), aspirinbin = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hypertension = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), hypertensionbin = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), lipids = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), lipidsbin = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), insulin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), insulinbin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    scheme = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), ID = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")), .Names = c("hai_dispense_number", 
"aspT1person", "aspT2person", "aspT3person", "aspbaseperson", 
"lipidT1person", "lipidT2person", "lipidT3person", "lipidbaseperson", 
"hyptenT1person", "hyptenT2person", "hyptenT3person", "hyptenbaseperson", 
"insulinT1person", "insulinT2person", "insulinT3person", "insulinbaseperson", 
"aspirin", "aspirinbin", "hypertension", "hypertensionbin", "lipids", 
"lipidsbin", "insulin", "insulinbin", "scheme", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**dput for merged df**

```
structure(list(hai_dispense_number = c("Patient HAI0000059", 
"Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", 
"Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", 
"Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059", "Patient HAI0000059"
), ID = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "2", 
"3"), variable.x = structure(c(1L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("month1", "month2", "month3", "month4", 
"month5", "month6", "month7", "month8", "month9", "month10", 
"month11", "month12", "month13", "month14", "month15", "month16", 
"month17", "month18"), class = "factor"), adherence = c(1, 0.866666666666667, 
0.833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.966666666666667, 0.6, 
0.833333333333333, 0.966666666666667, 1, 0.933333333333333), 
    time1 = c(-1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, -2, -3), new_numbers = c(-4L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, -3L, -2L), variable.y = structure(c(1L, 
    10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("t1", 
    "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", "t9", "t10", "t11", 
    "t12", "t13", "t14", "t15", "t16", "t17", "t18"), class = "factor"), 
    age = c(72, 72.75, 72.8333333333333, 72.9166666666667, 73, 
    73.0833333333333, 73.1666666666667, 73.25, 72.0833333333333, 
    72.1666666666667), sex = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    post = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), time_post = c(0, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0), base = c(3, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
    16, 17, 18, 4, 5), scheme = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), aspT1person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), aspT2person = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), aspT3person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), aspbaseperson = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1), lipidT1person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lipidT2person = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lipidT3person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lipidbaseperson = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), hyptenT1person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), hyptenT2person = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hyptenT3person = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hyptenbaseperson = c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), insulinT1person = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), insulinT2person = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), insulinT3person = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), insulinbaseperson = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    aspirin = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), aspirinbin = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hypertension = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), hypertensionbin = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), lipids = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), lipidsbin = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), insulin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), insulinbin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("hai_dispense_number", 
"ID", "variable.x", "adherence", "time1", "new_numbers", "variable.y", 
"age", "sex", "post", "time_post", "base", "scheme", "aspT1person", 
"aspT2person", "aspT3person", "aspbaseperson", "lipidT1person", 
"lipidT2person", "lipidT3person", "lipidbaseperson", "hyptenT1person", 
"hyptenT2person", "hyptenT3person", "hyptenbaseperson", "insulinT1person", 
"insulinT2person", "insulinT3person", "insulinbaseperson", "aspirin", 
"aspirinbin", "hypertension", "hypertensionbin", "lipids", "lipidsbin", 
"insulin", "insulinbin"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Which variables to you merge by?

Comment: merge by hai_dispense_number and ID

Comment: Are you doing `merge.data.frame(y=mymaindf, x=mergingdf, by=c("hai_dispense_number", "ID"))` ? That seems to work for me. Which variable is wrong in the result?

Comment: You have posted your dataframes, but we need also the code you are using to merge (I guess it's just oneline) and which is the column/row you expect to be different...

Comment: using the code which I posted in my question (just generalised it for sake of question- so in real terms its merge(mymaindf, mergingdf, by=c('hai_dispense_number', 'ID')).  the variable which changes is 'scheme'. @RockScience - i don't use merge.data.frame.... just merge. haven't had problems before with this! :(

Comment: @user2363642 Can you add this information in your question. FYI if you use merge on a data.frame R will use merge.data.frame. See http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-s3-oop-system/. Also can you provide with the dput of the output of the merge? On my side I see exactly the same as in mymaindf and mergingdf

Comment: @RockScience - have included above.... thanks for tips on question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mergingdf$scheme` is a `factor` , so its values are not what you think they are.

This could easily have been determined by simply typing , as I did,

`maindf$scheme` and `mergingdf$scheme` .

Comment: Hi @CarlWitthoft. the output above has a factor, but I also use as.character and as.numeric all with the same problem. it didn't seem to matter which way I set up the variable - it always changed.

Comment: @user2363642  to convert a factor, you need to use `as.numeric(as.character(the_factor))` . See the R-FAQ 7.10 .  Since you failed to mention this in your post and your comment about the code you used, you can understand why I didn't check for that.